# manage the operation priority when building ast with c grammar

Tags: c, operators, antlr, grammar, antlr3

I am trying to build an AST with my C grammar, wich can be found [here](http://sd-g1.archive-host.com/membres/up/24fe084677d7655eb57ba66e1864081450017dd9/cAST3.txt) . However it does not consider the priority with the operations, for exemple when I input this code :

```
 l = k*j*5 - 10;
```

I get this :

[image: AST]

The operations are managed by this code :

```
multiplicative_expression
: primary_expression (('*'^ additive_expression) | ('/'^ additive_expression) | ('%'^ additive_expression) )*
;

 additive_expression
: multiplicative_expression (('+'^ multiplicative_expression) | ('-'^ multiplicative_expression))*
;
```

Is there a solution to fix this please ?

Another question, is there a way to add a special token when building an AST ?
For example something like this :

```
A B C -> ^( "VAR" B C)
```

VAR is the new token that can only be seen with the AST.

And is it possible to rename the 'nil' token by something else ?

Comment: Your production for `multiplicative_expression` is wrong.

Comment: I suppose so too, but I don't know why it is wrong.

Comment: Since addition (and subtraction) have lower precedence than multiplication (and division), you can't have an `additive_expression` as a factor of a multiplicative expression. That production says `2*3+4` should be interpreted as `2*(3+4)`. If you replace `additive_expression` with `multiplicative_expression` in that production, you will have fixed that problem. However, then you still have the problem that `24/4/2` is interpreted as `24/(4/2)`, and it ought to be `(24/4)/2`. I'm not sure how to fix that in your setting.

Comment: I see, thank you. I will try to search for the division issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert in ANTLR, but shouldn't this do what you're looking for?

```
multiplicative_expression
: primary_expression (('*'^|'/'^|'%'^) multiplicative_expression)*
;

 additive_expression
: multiplicative_expression (('+'^|'-'^) multiplicative_expression)*
;
```

EDIT: Glad it worked for you. To Daniel Fischer's point about associativity, the solution that comes to mind is

```
multiplicative_expression
: primary_expression |
  (multiplicative_expression ('*'^|'/'^|'%'^) primary_expression)
;

 additive_expression
: multiplicative_expression |
  (additive_expression ('+'^|'-'^) multiplicative_expression)
;
```

However, I seem to recall reading that ANTLR at one point couldn't cope with left recursion like that. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunatly  it is still not what I am looking for, but it is still better. Here is what I get http://i.imgur.com/RyvRu6v.png

Comment: Sorry my bad, it works. It is just  that | additive_expression was in commentary.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for adding a new token, to do that I put this in the beginning :

```
 tokens {
     VAR;
 }
```

and then I could use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of correct [C grammars](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c) around, why not use one of them? Or at least start there?

Comment: Thanks for the link, in fact I did start from another grammaire : [this one](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/software/antlr_v3.2/examples-v3/java/C/C.g)